# Check if raster (part of) lies within a pixel - python/gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have a list of the corner-coordinates of different grid (c1-c4). First i sorted these coordinates to ensure that c1 is the upper left, c2 is the upper right, c3 is the lower left and c4 is the lower right coordinate. My second input is an empty grid with a given cellsize.

Now i want to get through every pixel in the empty grid and check with the four coordinates if they within the pixel of the empty grid.

It would be nice if somebody could help my. First i want to know how the get the x- and y-coordinate of every pixel in the grid.
Once the grid (blue) is inclined also the edge regions (grey) are excluded (see picture).

[image]